# How to get properties in spark dataframe that starts with '@'?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I call an api that I load in a dataframe and it's schema looks like that:

```
root
 |-- @odata.count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- @odata.nextLink: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
```

If I want to aces value property it that simple...

`df.select(col("value"))`

But if I want to aces @odata.count property with this piece of code:

`df.select(col("@odata.count"))`

I get this error: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`@odata.count`' given input columns: [@odata.count, @odata.nextLink, value];
'Project ['@odata.count]

I believe that the issue is the '@' char at the begining of property, but because I didn't have any control to that, I should find a way to read it.

Do you have any idea how to overcome this issue? There is a way to take that value by position?

Thanks

Comment: try escaping with a back tick  **`** around the column names

Comment: yep, that is the solution: `df.select(col("\`@odata.count\`"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @anky, the solution is:

```
df.select(col("`@odata.count`"))
```